# Objective-C decorator pattern, getting "Method definition not found"

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I'm implementing the Decorator Pattern with one class that "wraps" another. The specifics aren't important, but I want the ability to selectively override values returned by a `UICollectionViewDataSource`. So I need the ability to call the original method, then modify its return value.

I'm using [`forwardingTargetForSelector:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardingTargetForSelector:) to forward any unrecognized messages through to the wrapped object.

The problem is XCode complains that it can't find a method definition for any of the forwarded messages, and outputs tons of warnings.

Mike Ash describes this issue in a [blog post](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-03-27-objective-c-message-forwarding.html):

> **Declarations**
>
> Another consequence of Objective-C's C heritage is that the compiler needs to know the full method signature of every message that you're going to send in your code, even purely forwarded ones. To make a contrived example, imagine writing a class that uses forwarding to produce integers from code, so that you can write this:
>
> ```
> int x = [converter convert_42];
> ```
>
> The trouble is that the compiler doesn't know about any `convert_42` method, so it has no idea what kind of value it returns. It will give you a nasty warning, and will assume that it returns id. The fix to this is simple, just declare one somewhere:
>
> ```
> @interface NSObject (Conversion)
> - (int)convert_42;
> - (int)convert_29;
> @end
> ```
>
> Again, this obviously isn't very useful to do, but in cases where you have a more practical forwarding situation, this can help you make peace with the compiler. For example, if you use forwarding to fake multiple inheritence, use a category to declare all of the methods of the other class as applying to the multiply-inheriting class as well. That way the compiler knows that it has both sets of methods. One set gets handled by forwarding, but that doesn't matter to the compiler.

I did this, by creating a class category with just method definitions, but the compiler is complaining "method definition not found" so I think I misunderstood what Mike was writing.

How do I get rid of these warnings? Can I structure the decorator class differently, or do I need to just suppress warnings directly with a `#pragma`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I did this, by creating a class category with just method definitions, but the compiler is complaining "method definition not found" so I think I misunderstood what Mike was writing.

If you declare your class category correctly then you will not get the "method definition not found" warning.

For example:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end

@interface MyClass(MyForwardedMessages)
- (void)foo;
@end
```

As long as there is not a corresponding `@implementation MyClass(MyForwardedMessages)` block then you will not see warnings about a missing method implementation for `-foo`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could have a class category without an `@implementation` block